# Best way to use recent D3 versions to produce PNGs from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I'm wanting to use d3 server side to create PNG files, directly or via SVG.
I can find a number of discussions here about how to achieve this, but they're all from many years ago, referring to `d3` v3 or v4, and `node` back to v10.
Is it still necessary to pretend we're in a browser, providing a pseudo-DOM using something like `jsdom`?
Does the alternative `d3-node` family of packages actually still work? They're mostly not had updates for some years.

Here's my MNWE on node 17.0.1, d3 7.1.1, d3-node 2.2.3 on macOS 11.6:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const d3 = require('d3-node')().d3;
const output = require('d3node-output');
const d3nBar = require('d3node-barchart');
// const d3nPie = require('d3node-piechart');
// const csvString = fs.readFileSync('mentions.csv').toString();
const csvString=`key,value
Bob,33
Robin,12
...
Stacy,20
Charles,13
Mary,29`
const csvData = d3.csvParse(csvString);

const selector = `#chart`
const container = `<div id="container"><h2>Bar Chart</h2><div id="chart"></div></div>`
const style = `.bar{fill: steelblue;}
.bar:hover{fill: brown;}
.axis{font: 10px sans-serif;}
.axis path,.axis line{fill: none;stroke: #000;shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
.x.axis path{display: none;}`

// create output files
// const pie = d3nPie(csvData, selector, container, style)
const bar = d3nBar(csvData, selector, container, style)
output('output', bar);
```

I get the following errors in the penultimate line arising in the `d3node-barchart` library:

```
/Users/j/Dropbox/NP-other-tests/node_modules/d3node-barchart/index.js:55
  x.domain(data.map((d) => d.key));
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at bar (/Users/j/Dropbox/NP-other-tests/node_modules/d3node-barchart/index.js:55:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/j/Dropbox/NP-other-tests/d3test.cjs:45:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Would you mind editing the question to show the error message encountered?

Comment: Thanks, @Mehdi, now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Investigation

The error message tells that d3n-barchart does not find `data` where it expects it to be.

Looking at  the file throwing the error: `node_modules/d3node-barchart/index.js`, it appears that function `bar` expects one object as parameter, and not a data array as first parameter.

```
function bar({
  data,
  selector: _selector = '#chart',
  ...
```

It seems that the syntax shown in the [README of d3n-bar](https://github.com/d3-node/d3node-barchart/blob/master/README.md) is incorrect.

As shown in the [example file](https://github.com/d3-node/d3node-barchart/blob/master/example/index.js) of the library, function d3nBar takes one object as input parameter, with a `data` property.

### Solution

Applying the syntax from d3n-barchart's example file solves the error:

```
const bar = d3nBar({
    data: csvData
    , selector: selector
    , container: container
    , style: style
})
```

You might want to correct d3n-barchart's README file and submit a pull request, to help future users get their code right :)

Comment: Thanks so much, @Mehdi. Once I confirm this, I will certainly raise a PR for them.

Comment: Solution confirmed, and so I will raise a PR for them.